# Quit application x after y seconds of _application_ inactivity

Tags: applescript

My problem is related to an [earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/256783/mac-auto-quit-specific-programs-after-system-inactivity), where an application is quitted after user inactivity. What I'm looking for is however slightly different: how can I quit a specific application x after y seconds of *application* inactivity, i.e., if I have been active for 15 minutes, but not touched Firefox for 5 minutes: close it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you using a Mac, the same as the original question or are you using a PC? What have you tried so far? Have you found anything else that is close?

Comment: @Mokubai You are right – I'm on a Mac. What I've tried so far is simply scrolling around on Superuser for a variant on the problem + Googled for it, but haven't found any answer. I do not know if it's tricky to determine application inactivity, but there is seemingly no ready-to-go function for it in Automator, for example.